# Graphical glitch in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have encountered rather odd error in UITableViewCell. I have created a prototype cell in IB StoryBoard and then created it in standard way in UITableViewController. Somehow I am getting a graphical glitch pictured below.

Anybody has the same issue? It happens on both simulator and real device (iPhone 5).

[image: Error while drawing cell]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the separator of your cells.
You could remove the separator or set the left separator inset to zero. (select your table view in interface builder and tune the settings in the attributes inspector in the right panel)